# Show XLabs PopupLayout XAML in a ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I'm using XLabs / MVVM / IOC.
Someone please have a simple example (PopupLayout) in this scenario?

I mean XAML with no code behind.

For example, how to show this PopupLayout in my ViewModel?

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <controls:PopupLayout>
        <controls:PopupLayout.Content>
            <Button x:Name="OpenButton" Text="Open selector popup" />
        </controls:PopupLayout.Content>
    </controls:PopupLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According developer team:

> The PopupLayout isn't really meant to be XAML only control. You will
>   have to write some code-behind for it.

Comment: Bad news... Finally you used it?? I have the same problem.

Comment: I've decided not use it because I'm using MVVM without code behind.